# Generate custom documentation (based on SQL table)

Tags: sql, documentation, help-files

I'm currently using a software with its own command-line interface, accepting its own commands with parameters, but these commands are documented in several places and files, so I can't simply run doxygen on it, and its not possible to add documentation to these files now.

Dumping everything in one text document seems a bit annoying to use, so my first idea is to generate a table, SQL for example, and add the documentation there, with several columns, such as command and its description, arguments and description of them, example command, execution time, etc., and add some kind of GUI to easily display the commands.

Are there already solutions for this, especially easy to maintenance ones?
Or is it better to have a different approach for this, such as html based Helpfiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could build one yourself or use some third party tools like [REDGATE SQLdoc..](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc/index)

below is one example of how documentation is generated for one sample table as HTML,PDF as well

[image]